# Whenever I'm playing audio/video files, Left side of the headphone is not working whereas the right one does. How to correct this in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sound

Whenever I'm listening/playing audio/video files, Left side of the headphone is not working whereas the right one does. I tried checking out the systems, everything seems fine. Doesn't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you sure the headphones are working fine? Tried with phone or other OS?

Comment: Yes, Works absolutely fine on any other devices other than this laptop. Have tried on different PCs and Laptops, works fine.
Also, without the headphone also, I've tried checking sound going through settings, still the same problem.